# Can't run ASP.NET MVC 2 web app on IIS 7.5

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, iis, asp.net-mvc-2, iis-7.5

I'm trying to run an ASP.NET MVC 2 web application under IIS on Windows 7, but I get a 403.14 error. Here are the steps to reproduce:

1. Open Visual Studio 2010
2. Create a new ASP.NET MVC 2 project called MvcApplication1
3. Shift+F5 to run the app. You should see `http://localhost:{random_port}/` and the page will render correctly.
4. Click on MvcApplication1, and select "Properties". Go to the "Web" section.
5. Select "Use Local IIS Web server" and create a virtual directory.
6. Save.
7. Shift+F5 to run the app. You should see `http://localhost/MvcApplication1/` and an IIS error `HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.`.

It's clear that for whatever reason, ASP.NET routing is not working correctly.

Things I've already thought of and tried:

- Verified that all IIS features are enabled in "Turn Windows features on or off".
- Verified that the default website is configured to use .NET 4.0
- Reassigned ASP.NET v4 scripmaps via `aspnet_regiis -i` in the `v4.0.30319` directory.

Here's the most amazing part - this is on a *just-built* machine. New copy of Windows 7 x64 Ultimate, clean install of Visual Studio 2010 Premium, no other websites and no other work performed.

Anything else I can try?

[image: Setting Visual Studio to use local IIS web server]

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Ok, this is resolved for me, by doing the following:

Running `aspnet_regiis -i` in the **32-bit** directory `c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319`.

At this point, I don't understand why 64-bit mode isn't working, but I'm now unblocked. Hopefully this helps anyone else who is having this issue.

Comment: This was driving me crazy, how frustrating... fixed now. Cheers

Comment: Well now how late is this... This hasn't worked for me. Still getting an error about a default document not having been defined

Answer (score 46):

I had exactly the same issue, so thanks for your help.

However... did you try running the `aspnet_regiis -i` command in the Visual Studio 64 bit command prompt (with admin privileges)? When I did that it fixed it for the 64-bit mode.

To clarify, I right clicked on `Visual Studio x64 Win64 Command Prompt (2010)` and chose Run as Administrator. Then I went here:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319
```

And did this: `aspnet_regiis -i`

And now it works perfectly.

Answer (score 26):

Also ensure that you configuration file has the following line otherwise the routing will not work.

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: With VS 2012 using Local IIS (not IIS Express), this was the answer.  Thanks.

Comment: Didn't think this would do it. I'm glad I tried. (This was for .NET 4.5 MVC 4 app, too.)

Comment: Thanks so much! This worked for me. I'm new to .NET though, why wouldn't this have been included in the web.config to start with?

Answer (score 8):

Don't use runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests. You want to let IIS handle resources such as images.

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>
```

Instead add the MVC routing module

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules>
    <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" />
    <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition="" />
  </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 7):

Another thing to note, make sure your application pool is set to integrated, not classic

Answer (score 4):

I had this same problem on IIS8 / Windows Server 2012. None of the many proposed solutions worked until I tried the following.

```
dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:IIS-ASPNET45 /All
```

Without the '/All' switch it complained that a parent feature was not installed.

The strange thing is that according to Windows' *Turn Windows Features on or off* facility, asp.net 4.5 was already installed.

There was no need to make any changes to the web.config, add or remove modules.

Answer (score 0):

I've always used the custom server setting in VS 2008, which still allows me to debug with no problems. Not sure if it works any differently in 2010

Answer (score 0):

I had these symptoms; My `Global.asax` was crashing. Fixed the crash, everything is working now.

Comment: I accidentally excluded mine from deployment and (duh) deploying it fixed my issue.