# ASP.NET deployment issues (Not working in release mode)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, deployment, iis-7, release

I have an asp.net mvc 2 application which works fine when run from visual studio either in release or debug mode. When the application is deployed to either a remote or local IIS 7 server in release mode it doesn't work.

The error displayed is as follows:

HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.

Now this is a bit misleading however I have worked out why this error message is being displayed.

1. The application does not have a default.aspx as this is not needed when running mvc apps on IIS7+
2. I am using attribute routing which is explained in the link below which uses reflection to build the RouteTable. When interrogating the assembly the attributes are not accessible therefore the RouteTable does not get populated
3. Since there are no routes the web server attempts to list the directory contents and it does not have permission to do that.

Attribute Routing:

http://itcloud.codeplex.com/

[ASP.NET MVC Routing Via Method Attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894779/asp-net-mvc-routing-via-method-attributes)

Now my question is what is preventing the application from being able to interrogate the assembly using reflection?

DaTribe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lack of ReflectionPermission is a likely cause. Many hosting companies over-restrict permissions. Reflection is one that is often problematic. GoDaddy and RackSpace both restrict it.

What trust level is your application running? What hosting provider are you using? Do you have RDP access?

Comment: 1. The application is running in Full Trust (internal)
2. I have RDP acess
3. I am using www.ServerIntellect.com
4. Dedicated Server.

Comment: How do I go about using the reflection permission attribute?

Comment: In full trust you shouldn't need it, but [here is some info on it](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnfa/archive/2005/03/08/389768.aspx). Do you have an error log, or any way to determine if exceptions are being thrown during App_Start?

Comment: That what I thought, but as it stands this is the apps behaviour. I am having a look at the article. Very interesting read.

Comment: I have resolved the problem by installing the 32 bit .NET 4.0 framework (aspnet_regiis -i) and setting the application to Enable 32-bit applications. See article http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659544/cant-run-asp-net-mvc-2-web-app-on-iis-7-5. It seems there is a problem with .NET framework 64 bit mode running on IIS 7+ and windows server 2008 x64

Comment: I have resolved the problem by installing the 32 bit .NET 4.0 framework (aspnet_regiis -i) and enabling 32-bit applications in the application pool. See article http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659544/cant-run-asp-net-mvc-2-web-app-on-iis-7-5. It seems there is a problem with .NET framework 64 bit mode running on IIS 7+ and windows server 2008 x64

Comment: I have found the solution to this problem without have to resort to running the application in 32 bit mode. The routing code needs a slight adjustment. Interrogating not just the calling assembly but all assemblies within the app domain

Comment: sorry user181799 can you post the necessary code here?