# Error in running asp.net mvc website on server

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, web-hosting

I have uploaded my website on the server but it says resource not found. I also tried adding **/Home** and **/Home/Index**

Following is the url for my website :-

[Asp.net MVC project](http://techgeek.rdinvent.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that MVC is not installed on the server.  See these notes about doing a BIN deploy (basically copying the MVC runtime dlls into the bin directory).

http://haacked.com/archive/2011/05/25/bin-deploying-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx

The new `AddDeployableDependencies` functionality is pretty cool!

**EDIT:** Another possibility is that the IIS installation is somehow corrupted or the `web.config` has errors. See *all* the different answers to this question for more: [Can't run ASP.NET MVC 2 web app on IIS 7.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659544/cant-run-asp-net-mvc-2-web-app-on-iis-7-5)

Comment: tried copying everything...all the assemblies...Still no success....Dont know whats the reason.....

Comment: Try having a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659544/cant-run-asp-net-mvc-2-web-app-on-iis-7-5

Comment: I think the possible reason can be of no registeration of asp.net 4.0 .... May be the hosting provider is running 3.0 .....Do you also think this can be the reason ?? And if yes, then what can be done

Comment: That's certainly a possibility.  Are you able to set the Application Pool to use `ASP.NET 4.0` and `Integrated Pipeline`?  If they haven't installed .NET 4.0 then you should ask them to install it and change hosting provider if they don't.  Who is your hosting provider?

Comment: my hosting provider is [znetlive.com](http://znetlive.com). There is option for application pooling and stuff.....

Comment: I see you are getting a `403.14 error`.  In my experience this either means that ASP.NET MVC is not installed and you haven't done a successful bin deploy, or that there is a problem with the IIS installation.  Basically the two things I said in my original answer.  I tried to look at a demo account for znetlive.com, but it was a linux account, so no use.  If you have options around application pools try setting to `Dedicated Application Pool` and `.NET 4.0 Integrated Pipeline`.

Answer (score 0):

What is the default file that is executed? Maybe you should add your homepage file to the list in ISS? Default.aspx should be in there as default.