# IIS not running ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-7

I have deployed an asp.net MVC application to my IIS7 server.  When I attempt to browse the dafault route I get the message

HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden

The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.

It's clear to me that it is not loading/processing the global.asax, but I have no idea why.  I've deployed another MVC application to this same location/app pool and it works fine.

Does anyone have any idea how to debug a problem like this?

Comment: This is a valid question for asp.net programmers as () by the guidelines it describes a problem interacting with:  "software tools commonly used by programmers"

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Maybe:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/> 
</system.webServer>
```

OR

- [ASP.NET MVC on IIS 7.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374957/asp-net-mvc-on-iis-7-5)
- [ASP MVC in IIS 7 results in: HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741439/asp-mvc-in-iis-7-results-in-http-error-403-14-forbidden)
- [Can't run ASP.NET MVC 2 web app on IIS 7.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659544/cant-run-asp-net-mvc-2-web-app-on-iis-7-5)

Comment: Damnit!!! I discovered this 30 minutes later as well.  Looks like I won't get to answer my own question.

Comment: What file are you supposed to put this in?

Answer (score 21):

I've tried a lot, and finally one checkbox did the trick

[image]

Comment: This did the trick! Thanks a lot of the post! Any ideas on what exactly does that do and why is it needed? I assumed that IIS should come with all of the prerequisites that it might need?

Comment: This did the trick!! Why doesn't Microsoft mention this in documentation?? And yes, why wasn't it installed in the whole IIS installation?

Comment: Yet again the IT department forgot to add this to the developer image.. Thanks

Comment: You are right, this option must be enabled to make MVC ASP.NET work correctly