# ASP.NET MVC Routing: Need to use Index in URL despite it being declared in defaults (using Areas)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-areas

I have searched but no solutions seem to work for me.
I have a web forms VS2013 solution and I've been adding MVC to this using an Area. 
I have got everything working when I specify e.g.: `http://localhost:51961/MVC/contractfiles/index/`

This works fine, but I need it to go to the same page when i use:

```
http://localhost:51961/MVC/contractfiles/
```

instead I get HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden - The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.

My Area registration is:

```
    namespace PublicHealthCMS_L3.Areas.MVC
    {
        public class MVCAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration 
        {
            public override string AreaName 
            {
                get 
                {
                    return "MVC";
                }
            }

            public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
            {
                context.MapRoute(
                    "MVC_default",
                    "MVC/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                    new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                    namespaces: new[] {"PublicHealthCMS_L3.Areas.MVC.Controllers" }
                );
            }
        }
    }
```

And my contractfiles controller:

```
namespace PublicHealthCMS_L3.Areas.MVC.Controllers
{
    public class ContractFilesController : Controller
    {
        private PublicHealthCMSEntitiesMVC db = new PublicHealthCMSEntitiesMVC();

        // GET: MVC/ContractFiles
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            int ContractID = MySession.Current.ContractID;
            return View(db.pr_File_Select(242).ToList());
        }
```

Thanks for any help

Main route:

```
namespace PublicHealthCMS_L3
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "contractfiles", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                namespaces: new string[] { "PublicHealthCMS_L3.Controllers" }
            );

            //.DataTokens = new RouteValueDictionary(new { area = "MVC" } );

        }
    }
}
```

Global.asax Application_Start

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Code that runs on application startup     
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);            


            //RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

        }
```

I also have some webapi routes, WebApiConfig.cs:

```
namespace PublicHealthCMS_L3
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <section name="PublicHealthCMS_L3.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  <section name="glimpse" type="Glimpse.Core.Configuration.Section, Glimpse.Core" /></configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="RouteDebugger:Enabled" value="false"/>
    <add key="MessageNoContractSelected" value="No contract is selected, please click Search and select a contract" />
    <add key="MessageDeleteRecordFilesExist" value="This record has associated files, please expand the record and remove the files first before the record can be deleted" />
    <add key="Version" value="1.02" />
  <add key="RouteDebugger:Enabled" value="true" /></appSettings>
  <connectionStrings>   
    <add name="PublicHealthCMSConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=bcvPHDEVSQL;User Id=PublicHealth_User; Password=;Initial Catalog=PublicHealthCMS;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="PublicHealthCMSEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/CRMModel.csdl|res://*/CRMModel.ssdl|res://*/CRMModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=BCVPHDEVSQL;initial catalog=PublicHealthCMS;User Id=PublicHealth_User; Password=;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="PublicHealthCMSEntitiesMVC" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Areas.MVC.Models.CMSModel.csdl|res://*/Areas.MVC.Models.CMSModel.ssdl|res://*/Areas.MVC.Models.CMSModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=bcvPHDEVSQL;initial catalog=PublicHealthCMS;user id=PublicHealth_User;password=;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="20480" />
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb="*" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" validate="false" />
    <add path="glimpse.axd" verb="GET" type="Glimpse.AspNet.HttpHandler, Glimpse.AspNet" /></httpHandlers>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
      <assemblies>
        <!--<add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />-->
        <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Management, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
      </assemblies>
      <buildProviders>
        <add extension=".rdlc" type="Microsoft.Reporting.RdlBuildProvider, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
      </buildProviders>
    </compilation>
    <authentication mode="Windows">
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
      <!-- This denies access to the Anonymous/unregistered user -->
      <allow users="*" />
      <!-- This allows access to all registered users -->
    </authorization>
    <identity impersonate="false" />

    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0"></pages>
  <!-- Glimpse: This can be commented in to add additional data to the Trace tab when using WebForms
        <trace writeToDiagnosticsTrace="true" enabled="true" pageOutput="false"/> --><httpModules>
            <add name="Glimpse" type="Glimpse.AspNet.HttpModule, Glimpse.AspNet" />
        </httpModules></system.web>
  <system.webServer>

    <!--<directoryBrowse enabled="true" />-->
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"><add name="Glimpse" type="Glimpse.AspNet.HttpModule, Glimpse.AspNet" preCondition="integratedMode" /></modules>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />



      <!-- Your other remove tags-->
      <!--
      <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" />
       -->
      <!--Your other add tags-->
      <!--
      <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" path="*" verb="*" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition="" />-->
    <add name="Glimpse" path="glimpse.axd" verb="GET" type="Glimpse.AspNet.HttpHandler, Glimpse.AspNet" preCondition="integratedMode" /></handlers>
    <defaultDocument>
      <files>
        <!--<add value="Search.aspx" />-->
        <add value="Index.cshtml" />
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings />
    <client />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <applicationSettings>
    <PublicHealthCMS_L3.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="PublicHealthCMS_L3_ActiveDirectory_ActiveDirectory" serializeAs="String">
        <value>http://bcvmbiis02/tools/ActiveDirectory.asmx</value>
      </setting>
    </PublicHealthCMS_L3.Properties.Settings>
  </applicationSettings>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>

<glimpse defaultRuntimePolicy="On" endpointBaseUri="~/Glimpse.axd">
      <!-- 
          For more information on how to configure Glimpse, please visit http://getglimpse.com/Help/Configuration
          or access {your site}/Glimpse.axd for even more details and a Configuration Tool to support you. 
      -->
    </glimpse></configuration>
```

Also, the web.config within the MVC area:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="PublicHealthCMS_L3" />

      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>

  <appSettings>
    <!--<add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />-->
  </appSettings>

  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
      <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace this

```
new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

with this:

```
new { controller="ContractFiles", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

And try to rebuild the project. I just verified - and it works

Comment: Show your app route registration please

Comment: I've updated question to include Applicaiton_Start method of Global.asax and standard RouteConfig. Is that what you mean?

Comment: what is in RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes)?

Comment: try to rebuild the project. I just verified - and it works

Comment: Tried rebuilding and same error. The are 4 items within the RouteTable.Routes collection, I think it includes my webapi routes too, could it be something to do with these? I've included my WebApiConfig.cs? Many thanks

Comment: Your webapi route begins with /api/, so it should not hide area's route wich begins with /MVC/

Answer (score 0):

Try to add it in WebConfig file:

```
 <system.webServer>
   <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/> 
 </system.webServer>
```

and

```
    <system.webServer>
      <defaultDocument>
       <files>
      <add value="index.cshtml" />
      </files>
     </defaultDocument>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
    </system.webServer>
```

Please see the answer from "[IIS not running ASP.NET MVC application](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12735824/4275342)"

Comment: Thanks, I already tried this but the error shows when it is not running from the web server but from local dev PC,

Comment: HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden - The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory. It basically doesn't recognize the URL without Index. If I add index then it works fine.

Comment: @Blingers Did youi add defaultDocument in WebConfig?

Comment: Yes tried that and still the same error. I've added my web.config to the question if that helps. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This was a strange error and I've 'resolved' it by adding a new controller and copying and pasting everything from the existing controller into this new one. The new one works fine. Very irritating that I've spent 3-4 days trying to solve a problem that is obviously some sort of bug as the new controller is exactly the same as the existing one but works fine.